# How do i format a template string with this kind of data?

Tags: php, printf

im new to php and i need to process some log files from a database.

I got two datasets

1. details: `User %s logged in from %s (%s)`
2. log_data: `a:3:{i:0;s:2:"ba";i:1;s:9:"127.0.0.1";i:2;s:0:"";}`

My idea is to format `details` using `sprintf($details, $log_data)` but i don't know what kind of format `log_data` is. For me it looks a bit like json.

The result should be `User ba logged in from 127.0.0.1 ()`

Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: Why are you saving the data as serialized strings instead of having different columns for the different values (like a database is meant to be used)? In the way you have it now, you won't be able to query the database for specific users or do any grouping/joins etc

Comment: The duplicate answered my question, thanks! @MagnusEriksson jeah ... i'm writing a prometheus exporter for a shitty cms, can't change the data structure :(